# How to import a relative component with custom type bindings

Tags: typescript

So I have a project file path set like so:

```
app
  - src
    - views
      - mypage.vue
  - tsconfig.json
common
  - types
      - test.d.ts
  - test.js
```

However when I try to do an import of my test.js file like the following (in mypage.vue) I get the following errors based on how I implement the import.

**Attempt 1:**

import:

```
import * as test from '../../../common/test'
```

test.d.ts

```
declare module 'test' { ... }
```

Result:
`cannot find declaration file for ../../../common/test`

**Attempt 2:**

import:

```
import * as test from '../../../common/test'
```

test.d.ts

```
declare module '../../../common/test' { ... }
```

Result:
`module declaration cannot specify relative module name`

**Attempt 3:**

tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
    "@common/*": [
        "../common/*"
    ]
}
```

import:

```
import * as test from '@common/test'
```

test.d.ts

```
declare module '@common/test' { ... }
```

Result:

`Failed to compile with 1 error
This dependency was not found:
@common/test
To install it, you can run: npm install --save @common/test`

Comment: Instead of .js file why cant  you use that file as a service component? then that .js function will invoke

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, for now I've used `require('../../../common/test.js')` to avoid the issue. But this makes it ignore typescript bindings, so I don't think it's a solution.